# Check 301 http response with curl

Tags: php, symfony, http, curl

I'm migrating a web site. And I need to do the migration of more than 600 old url to a new type of url
with symfony routing and 301 permanent redirection.

example of one of my url:

```
redirect_test-url:
    path: /test-url
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /category/test-url
        permanent: true
```

The redirect seems to work. But I need to be sure that all my old url are redirected with a 301 redirect.
I think I can do a script with php and curl to check all the url. But I don't know how can get the curl result.

Here is my curl request:

```
curl https://local.dev -k
```

But my terminal jut send me back html.

How can I get the http status code response to store it in a database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dump the headers of the response with the `-D` option:

```
curl -s -D - http://www.martar.fr -o /dev/null
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 07:50:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Location: https://www.martar.fr/
Content-Length: 309
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

`-s` is for **Silent mode (don't output anything)**

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you want something similar to this:

```
curl -sI https://example.com -w '%{response_code}:%{redirect_url}\n' -o /dev/null
```

As a bonus, this gets you both the redirect code and the redirect target (if any).

Answer (score 1):

curl writeout variables in general extremly useful

```
curl -sI https://duravit.de -w '%{response_code}:%{redirect_url}:%header{server}\n' -o /dev/null
```

https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/verbose/writeout#variables